# How to find the longest string in a text using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

Given a string x, i can count the number of words (length) in this string using gregexpr("[A-Za-z]\w+", x) .

```
> x<-"\n\n\n\n\n\nMasters Publics\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMasters Universitaires et Prives au Maroc\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\n\n\n\n\nMasters Par Ville\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
> sapply(gregexpr("[A-Za-z]\\w+", x), function(x) sum(x > 0))
[1] 11
```

However, how can i retrieve the number of words in the longest attached string (with space and not \n), using regex under R environnent

in this example it would be  "Masters Universitaires et Prives au Maroc" which length is 6 .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: I get `11` when running your code. Do you want to return the number of words in the longest line?

Comment: Yes the number of words in the longest line

Comment: Try [`max(nchar(gsub("[^ ]+", "", unlist(strsplit(trimws(x), "\n+"))))) + 1`](http://ideone.com/SWMlxj) - is that what you need? Or do you need to use `gregexpr` by all means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it with

```
x <- "\n\n\n\n\n\nMasters Publics\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMasters Universitaires et Prives au Maroc\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\n\n\n\n\nMasters Par Ville\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
max(nchar(gsub("[^ ]+", "", unlist(strsplit(trimws(x), "\n+"))))) + 1
```

Split a trimmed string into lines, unlist the result, remove all characters other than a space, get the longest item and add one. The `[^ ]+` is a regex that matches one or more (due to the `+` quantifier) characters other than (as `[^...]` is a *negated character class*) a space.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SWMlxj).

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, I gave a wrong vote. I wanted to give you a positive vote, but I was wrong. If you edit the answer I can rectify my vote.

Comment: @PereG: I added a small explanation of the `[^ ]+` regex.

Answer (score 1):

Load the package

```
library(stringr)
```

Create a new dataset, extracting and splitting the phrases

```
data <- unlist(str_split(x, pattern="\n", n = Inf))
index <- lapply(data, nchar)
index <- index !=0
# extract the maximum length of the phrase

max(sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", data[index]), length) + 1)
[1] 6

# just checking
data[index]
[1] "Masters Publics"                          
[2] "Masters Universitaires et Prives au Maroc"
[3] "\\n"                                      
[4] "Masters Par Ville"
```